# Couldn't save to MS Access database from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

The values staring vith cmb is a combo box. When I click the save button, it throws an error.

My code is here:

```
cn.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = cn;
command.CommandText = "insert into TblProductDetails(ProductID, ProductName, Category, Section, UOM, CostPrice, SellingPrice1, SellingPrice2, DiscountPercentage, DiscountAmount, MinimumPrice, Vendor, Stock) values ('" + txtProductID.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + category + "','" + section + "','" + uom + "','" + txtCostprice.Text + "','" + txtSellingPrice1.Text + "','" + txtSellingPrice2.Text + "','" + txtDiscountpercentage.Text + "','" + txtDiscountAmount.Text + "','" + txtMinimumPrice.Text + "','" + vendor + "','" + txtBeginingStock.Text + "')";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: *"it throws an error"* - what exactly? Can you provide error text?

Comment: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: I suppose you see a Syntax Error because Section is a reserved keyword. But this is just the first of your problems with that query text

Comment: and the string values (category,section,UOM and vendor) are combo box values

Comment: As expected. Put the word Section between square brackets `[Section]` then start ASAP to look at how to write parameterized queries

Comment: oh thank u i will check it bro

Comment: now it shows this error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.)

Comment: Again, stop and study how to write parameterized queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Your DataBasePath";
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TblProductDetails (ProductID, ProductName, Category, Section, UOM, CostPrice, SellingPrice1, SellingPrice2, DiscountPercentage, DiscountAmount, MinimumPrice, Vendor, Stock) VALUES(@ProductID, @ProductName, @Category, @Section, @UOM, @CostPrice, @SellingPrice1, @SellingPrice2, @DiscountPercentage, @DiscountAmount, @MinimumPrice, @Vendor, @Stock)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UOM", textBox4.Text);
        // continue Your Code its just example 
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank You Bro. This helped me

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things. See comment from Steve. But you also want to check the values in the text boxes for the " **'** " character (apostrophe) as if the text box contains that character then that could also cause syntax issues, check out SQL injection for more information on that. Thought this was worth a mention. You could use a DataTableAdapter for this kind of thing too, or Entity Framework just to clear that up a little (I would do).